# Cannot update data in a MySQL View via Workbench or MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, view, mysql-workbench, insert-update

I created a MySQL Schema db1002 using the workbench. It has one table: id (key, AI) and Name (char45). and the following view:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE DEFINER = `xxxx`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `new_view` AS
    select `candidates`.`id` AS `id`, `candidates`.`name` AS `name`
    from  `candidates`
```

According to mysql documentation, this view should be updatable. That means, in the workbench I query the view (select * from db1002.new_view).
It shows 1 record = all records. 
But, I can't update or insert any record. Normally I can click on a field in the results list and change it. I can't. The new record line (with *) is also missing.
If I connect to it through ODBC using MSACCESS I also cn't update the table. 
In the information_schema the view is listed is_updatable = yes.

Btw, I can update the underlying table candidates without any problems.

What is wrong here?

Thanks to everybody helping me out.

Update: I tested something else: if I use the "update `new_view` set name is pete" on the view, it works. However, if I use the workbench I can't update by typing directly into the record. E.g. if if use "select * from candidates " (i.e. the table) then I can update by typing directly into the result list and I can add a new record as well. Try the same by "select * from new_view" and I can't. 
Also, I use MS Access as a front-end. If I access the table candidates, I can update and add records. If I access the new_view instead, I can't. 
So basically, the view is updateable, but only through the update command but not through the usual methods. Which in MS Access is a big problem.

Comment: My guess is that the specified user doesn't have update permissions on the table.

Comment: The user can update the table

Comment: Unrelated but: you most certainly do **not** want `char(45)`. That datatype is always padded with spaces to the defined length. I'm pretty sure you want `varchar(45)` for a column called `name`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to recreate your setup but not your issue. I could insert a new row into the Linked Table [new_view] in Access simply by opening the Linked Table in Datasheet View and typing into the New Record (`*`) row.

Replication steps: To create the MySQL database, table, and view:

```sql
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 03, 2014 at 10:08 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.13
-- PHP Version: 5.4.17

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `db1002`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db1002` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `db1002`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `candidates`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` char(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `candidates`
--

INSERT INTO `candidates` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Gord');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Stand-in structure for view `new_view`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_view` (
`id` int(11)
,`name` char(45)
);
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure for view `new_view`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `new_view`;

CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `new_view` AS select `candidates`.`id` AS `id`,`candidates`.`name` AS `name` from `candidates`;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

To create the ODBC System DSN

[image: OdbcDriver.png]

[image: OdbcDsn.png]

To create the Linked Table in Access, **note the dialog to select the "Unique Record Identifier" (i.e., the Primary Key) for the linked table -- it's important:**

[image: External.png]

[image: SelectDataSource.png]

[image: LinkTables.png]

[image: UniqueRecordIdentifier.png]

To test the linked table in Access

[image: DataSheetView.png]

Comment: Gord, you're a hero !!!!!
The issue was in linking the tables in msaccess and selecting the primary key during that process. I always jump through that thinking it has been defined already at the server.
But, to update the view the primary key must be defined. 
Interesting is, that the workbench has the same problem. But that is not so important now.

Comment: @user3263493 Glad to hear that you got it working. It's a fairly common stumbling block when creating a Linked Table connected to a View. Access will recognize an existing Primary Key when linking to a *Table*, but it needs to be told what fields to use when linking to a *View*.

Comment: That's the right answer for MS Access, but where do you specify the "primary key" for an updatable view in MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW `new_view`

(`id`, `Name`)

AS

 select `candidates`.`id` AS `id`, `candidates`.`name` AS `name`
    from  `candidates
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried, but same result.